# how to check date in c#? (interactive program)

Tags: c#, datetime, if-statement

i'm learning to create an interactive program where users type their exact birthday(month; day, year) at separate lines but i don't know how to use `DateTime.Now` property. I know `month` has to be from 1 to 12 so i wrote

```
if (month<1  && month>13)
{Console.WriteLine("error");}
```

+with `"year"` field, it has to be from 18 to 100 years ago. i used

```
if(year >2000 &&year <1918)
{Console.WriteLine("error");}
```

the problem is,i have to change the conditions each year . and i also want to check the relationship between `"day"` field and `month` field. for example February only has 28 days; if `day` field exceeded, prompt "error". I know it's complicate but i don't know a lot about `DateTime` property and how to cooperate that to a condition statement . please help. thanks

Comment: Btw those if statements will never be true. You can't be both greater than 13 AND less than 1 at the same time. Use  `||` (and I think you mean >=13)

Comment: If these answers have provided a solution mark one has correct, or if you have a suitable answers of your own, answer your own question and mark it correct to help future readers

Answer (score 1):

```
 dateString = "2011-29-01";//concatenate fields to get date
 string format = "yyyy-dd-MM";
 try
 {
   //for ParseExact : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx
   result = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, format, provider);
   Console.WriteLine("{0} converts to {1}.", dateString, result.ToString());
  }
  catch (FormatException)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("{0} is not in the correct format.", dateString);
   }

   if(result.AddYears(18)<=Datetime.now){
   //write your logic
   }
```

Comment: This explains nothing and is a A/B solution. You also do not explain where to get provider from.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

[DateTime.Year Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.year(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Gets the year component of the date represented by this instance.

[DateTime.DaysInMonth Method (Int32, Int32)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.daysinmonth(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Returns the number of days in the specified month and year.

**Eg**

```
var currentYear = DateTime.Now.Year;

if (year > currentYear - 18 || year < currentYear - 118)
{
   Console.WriteLine("error"); 

}
```

and

```
var days = DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, 2);

// calculate the days in February for a given year
if (day > days || day < 0)
{
   Console.WriteLine("error");

}
```